# Synology: SMART status is abnormal but no errors shown

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, nas, smart, synology

I have a [Synology DS509+](http://techwiki.hardwarecanucks.com/product/1NjEyNTk0NTYxNTI/Synology-Disk-Station-DS509/#spec) NAS that is showing an "Abnormal" S.M.A.R.T. status for one of its drives:

[image]

However, there seems to be nothing wrong with the S.M.A.R.T. test results:

[image]

So, what's going on? Are any of the values shown above dangerous and incorrectly reported as "OK" or is the disk incorrectly reporting S.M.A.R.T. errors?

Answer (score 1):

Search the model on Google, it is a Green drive.

They have a freature called "Intellipark", which is not so intelligent after all. This feature parks the heads of the drive after 8 seconds of idle activity, and acess to the disk will unpark the heads. Due do this feature and some patterns of use, like Linux and some Windows applications, this count would go sky-high.

This worried some users because user-grade drives were certified to 300.000 load/unload cycles, and with the heads parking twice every minute, it would get 2 * 60min * 24h = 2880, and 300.000/2880 makes the drive have a lifespan of 104 days.

**Yeah, you are luck to have such a good drive that did not fail until now.**

If you are worried about that, Western Digital launched the [WDIDLE3 utility](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=609&sid=113&lang=en) some time ago to change the time needed of idle activity to park the heads.

Here are some things that you can read about this problem:

- [A topic at Western Digital forums](http://community.wd.com/t5/My-Book-Live/Very-high-Load-Cycle-Count-over-5-000-in-less-than-180h/td-p/151544);
- [Western Digital Knowledge Base](http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5357);
- [Sysnology Forums](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=124&t=11682&sid=2aed763304351bcebd7e7ec49beda77e).

That's it.

Comment: Nevermind, I overlooked it.  Yes it's got the high power cycle count.  No that's not the reason for the 'abnormal'   afaik, Load_Cycle_Count does not trigger SMART to error like that.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not the definitive resource on SMART but it looks to me that Reallocated_Sector_Ct is one that's high.  Value is 200 threshold is 140.  Reallocated Sectors are drive blocks that are rewritten/moved due to the original block being bad or defective.  Too many bad blocks typically indicates a failing drive.  If that rises any higher, plan on replacing it quickly.

Comment: -1: This is incorrect. A SMART attribute failure only occurs when the value falls *below* the threshold. In addition, the raw value for this attribute is zero, so there are no reallocated sectors.

Comment: You are correct.  Not sure how I crossed that up - I read it as 181.  Gonna have to chalk it up to late night blurred vision.  Do I just delete my answer (as it's pretty off base) or ?

Answer (score -1):

The issue is actually caused by ID 197 and 198.  There is currently 1 bad sector pending reallocation but no available sectors to reallocate to.  The reallocated sector count is 0 so this drive should be repairable using Western Digital software to repair the drive.